# chkdsk: setting a specific path is not working

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path, chkdsk

I can set the drive (volume), but not directory path or file path. `chkdsk` (with `/h`) utility shows  that I could set the optional parameter `path` and `filename`, but I get the following message instead.

```
>chkdsk c:\Users /f
The drive, the path, or the file name is not valid.
```

The following command is the same one from the [Microsoft help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714.aspx), but I still get the same error:

```
>chkdsk *.* /f
The drive, the path, or the file name is not valid.
```

Is there a reason why this is not working? I am using Windows 7 Pro x64 and the filesystem is NTFS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What’s the file system of the path? Remember the filename parameter isn’t for NTFS so if you need to check the whole drive the command is [chkdsk C: /f]

Comment: could you please let me know where you found this information? My guess is that `chkdsk` calls `chkntfs` automatically?

Comment: Chkntfs only modifies the autochk behaviour a boot-time, which in-turn watches chkdsk actions. From running chkdsk /? You can see that only “FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies the files to check for fragmentation”
This is what I understand of it however.

Comment: This is a reasonable explanation: http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/What-is-CHKNTFS